# how to get values in jsp using jstl from hashmap without iteration?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i am a newbie i have a hash map declared as

```
 HashMap map = new HashMap();

    map.put("code", code);
    map.put("url", evaluationTSRCode);
```

and iam passing this map in my modelandview contoller like this

```
return new ModelAndView("purchaseProduct","map","map");
```

how to access the values code,evaluationTSRCode in jsp using jstl without using iteration
i tries like this but i could not get the values.

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="(${map.code} != null && ${map.code}=!"" )" >
<td>You can purchase<a href='<c:url value="${map.url}"/>'>Directly</a></td>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
td>You can purchase Directly</td>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

please help me in solving this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: try accessing it by  
${map['Key']}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are accessing the map values in JSP is totally wrong.

There is one assumption from my side in your code

```
return new ModelAndView("purchaseProduct","map","map");
```

is wrong it should be

```
return new ModelAndView("purchaseProduct","map",map);
```

You don't need to iterate through the map values.

Eg. To access the value of code. `${map.code}` in jsp anywhere would be sufficient.

Or you can use like

```
return new ModelAndView("purchaseProduct", map);
```

and when you do this in JSP you just need to access the map value by its name only.

Eg. To access the value of code. `${code}` in jsp anywhere would be sufficient.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: yes its working but i can access the map values like ${map.code} or ${map['code']}.. then only its getting value

Comment: to access my map values code,url in jsp ustil jstl, i need to use like this format ${map.code} or ${map['code']} to get the value of 'key'(code) in map in jsp.

Comment: Ohhk. Now I get your realy problem.

You are adding your map in the model and view abject wrongly.

Try using the following.

`return new ModelAndView("purchaseProduct", map);`

And after that in your jsp you just need to access like **${code}**.

I bet now this will work for sure. :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Hope you are now satisfied with the asnwer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think an answer a bit more correct is still using map as suggested, but adding it to the ModelMap, declared in input of the controller method and returning only the string with the view name (I always use this way to refer views in spring controller):

```
public String themethod(ModelMap model) {
  ...
  model.addAttribute("map",map);
  return "purchaseProduct";
```

In this way you can use ${map.code} in your jsp.

More interestingly, if needed, you could package complex data structure in a map and then in a list

```
  List<Map<String, Object>> lcli = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
  for(Cliente c:cli) {
        Map <String,Object>map  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        int nord    = userDao.nord(c);
        map.put("cli", c);
        map.put("nord", nord);

        lcli.add(map);
    }
    mo.addAttribute("lcli", lcli);
```

In this way in the jsp you could iterate each element of the list, tagged lcli, that it is a map, from which pick up its keys/values as said, as below

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:forEach var="itemcli" items="${lcli}">
        <a href="<c:url value='edit-client.html?id=${ itemcli.cli.id }'/>" >   ${itemcli.cli.nome}  </a>            
        ${itemcli.cli.citta}
</c:forEach>
```